# PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters - Which computer is it referring to?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, printing

If I'm calling PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters in my web application; is that referring to the printers on the computer that the site is being hosted on, or the printers on the computer of the user that's accessing the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing **Server** Side code, so the `InstalledPrinters` are for the server.